# How to parse a timestamp used by PRTG

Tags: datetime, go, timestamp

I have a datetime string this format
`44340.5416666667` but i want to convert this to `5/24/2021 3:00:00 PM - 4:00:00 PM` format. How can i parse that with golang? I tried some convert function but it didn't work.

Comment: What `44340.5416666667` is means? can you mention some tried methods to get an idea?

Comment: I have a xml response from return api
```<item>
    <datetime>5/24/2021 3:00:00 PM - 4:00:00 PM</datetime>
    <datetime_raw>44340.5416666667</datetime_raw>
</item>```
I wanna convert this second row to first row.

Comment: yes, what `44340.5416666667` means? is it unix like format which time represents? or some duration in minutes, seconds or something like that?

Comment: My guess is that it's a Star Trek "star date". It certainly resembles one!

Comment: I don't know which format so i cannot convert this. This xml return prtg network manager. I am searching datetime format but i didn't find yet.

Comment: "parse to output" doesn't make sense. Parsing is the interpretation of input.

Comment: According to https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/1313-how-do-i-translate-prtg-timestamp-values-format-to-normal-time-format, this timestamp format is defined as the value of days since 12/30/1899.

Comment: I wonder if this PRTG serial date also has the same "bug" as [implemented in Excel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/1313-how-do-i-translate-prtg-timestamp-values-format-to-normal-time-format, the timestamp format used by PRTG seems to be defined as the value of days since Dec 30, 1899.

Following the above link, the following Go code should convert the timestamp into a Go `Time` instance:

```
prtg := 44340.5416666667
// substract number of days between Dec 30, 1899 and Jan 1, 1970 and convert to millis
millis := int64((prtg - 25569) * 86400 * 1000)
t := time.Unix(0, millis*int64(time.Millisecond))
println(t.Format("1/2/2006 03:04:05 PM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [prtg timestamp](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/1313-how-do-i-translate-prtg-timestamp-values-format-to-normal-time-format) mentioned in *Gregor Zurowski*'s comment,
convert your time to `nano seconds` (minimum unit in time to more accurate) and add unix nano of 1899-12-30 12.00 midnight.
re convert it to time and format it as below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    startDate := time.Date(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).UnixNano()
    timeVar := 44340.5416666667                                  //your time variable
    duration := startDate + int64(float64(24*60*60) * timeVar * 1e9) //duration since start date in nanoseconds

    fmt.Println(time.Unix(0, duration).Format("1/2/2006 03:04:05 PM"))
}
```